# Return all users from MongoDB database as an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, heroku

I am trying to return all the users in my MongoDB database with this function:

`

```
// get ALL users
router.get("/all", async (req, res) => {
    User.find({}, function (err, users) {
        var userMap = {};
        users.forEach(function (user) {
            userMap[user._id] = user;
        });

        res.send(userMap);
    });
});
```

`

However, I am getting:

```
2022-11-12T23:39:52.878941+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/users/all" host=sandboxhackathonapi.herokuapp.com request_id=0f0e9bac-c888-4222-b9f7-da00645a544d fwd="128.187.116.5" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=273 protocol=https

2022-11-12T23:39:52.878399+00:00 app[web.1]: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "all" (type string) at path "_id" for model "User"
```

How can I return all the users from a MongoDB database?

```
// User schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    gender: String,
    height: String,
    age: Number,
    race: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    country: String,
    isModel: Boolean,
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
});
```

This is my user schema

I tried different ways to return the users, but I just want to return in the form of an array of users.

Comment: your code looks ok, i think you are having conflict in your routes and seems you have a route `/api/users/:id` and it's getting `all` as id. are you sure your `/all` endpoint get call?

Comment: @1sina1 you were right about this, for some reason my endpoint was not getting called and instead it was calling /:id. I am not sure why, but once I commented the other one out it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to wait for the result first:

```
let users = await User.find();
```

Then you can map over your users:

```
let userMap = users.map((user) => {return user._doc});
```

Finally send your users back:

```
res.send(userMap);
```